# Recommended place to save iOS game data without iCloud support

Tags: ios, icloud

What is the recommended place to save game data if I do not want automatically to be backup to iCloud ?     I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` for iCloud, and have custom logic for updates.
So I do not for iCloud backup to mess things up.

By my understanding that is: `Library/Caches/`.

Because: `Documents/` and `Library/Preferences/` are backup to iCloud.

Am I correct ?

Comment: If it is a simple state, you can use: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"SOME_VALUE" forKey:@"SOME_KEY"];` (remember to `synchronize`)

Comment: @Raptor but this will be backup to iCloud ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `/Library/Cache` for storing such kind of information. Look what [Apple Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) says:

> Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in
>   the /Library/Caches directory.

You can save all your data to `/Documents`, just flag it so that it wouldn't copy to iCloud:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
        forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }

    return success;
}
```

You can use this method in your AppDelegate or wherever you create these files. Note that you can exlude from iCloud backup not only specific files, but directories too.

Comment: One more question. What will happen if I add file to `Documents/`, iCloude do backup and after that I set that file to NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey. I suppose that iCloud will not try to restore it ? Does any body have any experience with it ?

Comment: WI'm not sure, but I think that you're right, iCloud will simply remove it from stored backup.

Comment: do you know is this implemented on iOS ? Do they use some flag on file or have some settings somewhere else. I am asking because I would like to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also exclude the specific game data from performing backup to iCloud.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [url lastPathComponent], error);
}
return success;
```

Comment: That's a duplicate answer.

Comment: Yes, I see. You added the code after I did, but no matter. As long as he has his answer it's OK.